# Functional "Square Root" of $1/(x+1)$

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I've been dabbling in functional iteration lately, but I've run into a problem that's causing me a lot of grief.
First I tried to iterate the softplus function $f(x)=\ln(e^x+1)$, which wasn't hard. By a preexisting theorem, any function of the form $g(h(g^{-1}(x)))$ iterated $n$ times is given by $g(h^n(g^{-1}(x)))$, so the nth iterate of the softplus function is given by $f^n()=\ln(e^x+n)$. I've been mostly focused on functional square roots (a half-iteration of a function), and in this case, the functional square root was $\ln(e^x+\frac{1}{2})$.

Then I tried iterating a very similar function: $f(x)=-\ln(e^x+1)$. This proved to be much more difficult, because in order to put it in the form $g(h(g^{-1}(x)))$, I have to let $h(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$. Then, to find the functional square root, I would have to find the functional square root of $h(x)$. So far, I haven't been able to do this, but I've convinced myself that the answer will contain imaginary exponents. Can somebody please tell me how to do this (or how to find out if it is possible or not)?

Comment: $h(x)$ is a fractional linear map, hence a functional square root of it is given by a matrix square root for $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @quasi: all right, turned into an answer.

Comment: Perhaps this exploratory article of mine is interesting for you: http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/FracIterAltGeom.htm

Comment: I've solved the half iterate of $f(x)=-\ln(\exp(x)+1) $ using the Schröder-mechanism, which makes the ansatz $ g°^h(x) = \sigma(c^h \sigma^{-1}(x))) $ where $g(x) = f(x+ t)-t$ and $t$ is the attracting fixpoint near $-0.4812 $ and $c\approx -0.381$ is some constant("Lyapunow exponent" or "eigenvalue"). For instance $f°^{0.5}(-0.25) = -0.476215460298 + 0.149536581699 î$ and reinserted this value in the half-iterate function gives $-0.575939419879$ which is near the true value of $f(-0.25)$ by $1e-33$ and can made arbitrarily precise. However, this is different to your ansatz, so ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $h(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ is a fractional linear map, it is enough to devise a matrix square root for $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ to have a functional square root for $h(x)$.

If I am not wrong, this approach gives $$ \frac{\sqrt{1-2 i}+x\sqrt{-1+2 i} }{\sqrt{4+2 i}+x\sqrt{1-2 i}} = \color{red}{\frac{1+ix}{(1+i)+x}}$$ as a functional square root of $\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Comment: The idea of using a matrix square root for this question is great, but I don't think your answer works -- the actual answer is more complicated.

Comment: @quasi: what do you mean? $\frac{1+ix}{(1+i)+x}$ is a functional square root for $\frac{1}{1+x}$. I never told that there is a unique function with such a property.

Comment: Another functional square-root employs the interpolation of fibonacci numbers (involving complex numbers, not the "real-values-only" version), see the link in my other comment. This gives the solution equivalent to the classical Schröder-mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, it's right -- I must have made a mistake. I computed a much more complicated square root. Mine works, but yours is so much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

With an explorative approach we could first look at rational expressions of the iterates to positive *integer* heights and try, whether this gives a scheme for a continuous interpolation.
What we get for the first few iterates is
$$ f°^1(x) = {1+0x\over 1+1x} \qquad
 f°^2(x) = {1+1x\over 2+1x} \qquad
 f°^3(x) = {2+1x\over 3+2x} \qquad
 f°^4(x) = {3+2x\over 5+3x} \cdots
$$
and a pattern of Fibonacci-numbers $fib_k$ is much suggestive (and can also be proven)
$$ f°^h(x) = {fib_h+fib_{h-1}x\over fib_{h+1} + fib_h x} \tag 1 $$
Since the Fibonacci-numbers have a generalization to continuous indexes we have the option to define the fractional iterates based on this generalized Fibonacci-numbers.

---

The most common$\,^{[1]}$ Fibonacci-generalization is that based on the [Binet-formula][1]:
Let $\Phi = {1+\sqrt 5 \over 2} \approx 1.618... $ then the Binet-formula gives
$$ fib_h = {\Phi^h - (1-\Phi)^h\over \sqrt 5} \tag 2$$
If $h=0.5$ as asked here, we have to use $fib_{-0.5}, fib_{0.5},fib_{1.5} $ in formula (1). That three generalized Fibonacci-values are to be inserted
$$ fib_{-0.5} \approx 0.351577584254 + 0.568864481006 î \\
 fib_{ 0.5}  \approx 0.568864481006 - 0.351577584254 î \\
 fib_{ 1.5}  \approx 0.920442065260 + 0.217286896752 î \\
$$
A massive reduction of the explicite formula (1) when that values are inserted, however, can be done when we simply cancel $fib_h$. We have then formally 
$$ f°^h(x) = {1 +{fib_{h-1}\over fib_h}x\over {fib_{h+1} \over fib_h}+  1x} \tag 3 $$
and for $h=0.5$ we get here the handy coefficients ${fib_{h-1}\over fib_h} = 1 î $ and ${fib_{h+1}\over fib_h} = 1 + 1 î $ such that we can write the compacted formula
$$ f°^{0.5}(x) = {1 + 1 î x\over (1 + 1 î )+  1x} \tag 4 $$
which is identical to that already given solution of Jack D'Aurizio.

---

The intention of this answer is to show one way, how to generalize that fractional iteration formula to other values than actually $h=1/2$ only.

<sub>$\,^{[1]}$ There is also a real-to-real-interpolation common (see wikipedia; in an earlier thread here in MSE I've discussed the difference between that two methods); I didn't check what we would get here with that method</sub>

---

***late update:*** a far more explicited version of this I have in an earlier essay on exactly that subject: see [here](https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/FracIterAltGeom.htm) from [mathindex at my homepage](https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/)

Comment: I had noticed the fibonacci sequence pattern but I ran into a problem trying to find the "1/2th fibonacci number". It didn't occur to me to use the formula, though, so thanks for that.

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Great answer! Ironically, it seems your approach doesn't work in the case when one uses the real-to-real interpolation of the fibonacci sequence in the case when $h=1/2$, because then the function becomes a constant. But I think it does work for all other values of $h$ !

Comment: Hello @MaxMuller - hmm, long time I didn't at this problem. I think I've had a plot (maybe here in MSE), where I displayed the Binet-type interpolation. I've never "liked" the real-to-real-solution, so I have it not at the top of my head at the moment what that interpolation would show; but perhaps it were nice to draw a picture containing both types of trajectories together...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this general approach :

$$f(f(x))=g(x)=\int_0^{f(x)}f'(s)ds+C=\int_0^1f'(f(x)u)f(x)du+C$$

By letting $s=f(x)u$. Then $$\int_0^1f'(f(x)u)f(x)-g(x)du=0\forall x$$

Thus the integrand is orthogonal to the constant 1 function and hence it can be written after orthogonalizing any non constant in u function to 1 via Gram-Schmidt as :

$$f'(f(x)u)f(x)-g(x)+C=h(x,u)-\int_0^1 h(x,s)ds$$

Thus $$f'(f(x))f'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}(g(x)+h(x,1)-\int_0^1h(x,s)ds-C)=g'(x)$$

So that : $$ln(f(x))=D+\int_0^x\frac{g'(u)}{g(u)+h(u,1)-\int_0^1h(u,s)ds-C}$$, giving then f.

Comment: I noticed this just complicate the equation since h(x,u) cannot be any function of x but the expression has to be substituted in the original expression which gives an horrible equation for h. So it is useless.